# Can't edit tags following migration

Tags: bug, retagging

I just migrated [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/126573/11281) from EE.SE, and as frequently happens, the tags didn't carry over. So I tried to edit it to add the [wiring](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wiring) and [switch](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/switch) tags — something I do regularly on other sites — but the system here insisted that I need to also make a significant change to the text of the question as well, and refused to accept the edit.

Is this a bug?

Comment: That is likely related to having less than 2k of reputation. See the privileges to [edit the question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit).

Comment: But, as I said, I can do this on other sites on which I have even less rep. Yes, the edit goes into a review queue, but the system doesn't refuse it outright.

Comment: Did you make an accidental change to the question itself (adding a space somewhere)? There's also the edit to add those tags that went through before your question was posted here, so you may have been trying to make an edit that had already been made to the question.

Comment: No, the OP made his edit after I had already given up.